# SQL Trigger, set year to current year

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a trigger that sets the joined attribute to the current year.  This is what I have working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER foo2
BEFORE INSERT ON memberof
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN :new.joined := 2012;
END;
```

I want to change 2012 to the code below but keep getting compiler errors.  What's the proper syntax to accomplish this?

```
select extract(year from sysdate) from dual
```

Comment: Which DBMS is this? Oracle? if so - please tag that.

Comment: @WillHughes yes oracle, sorry

Comment: Why?  This is what a DEFAULT constraint is meant for, not a trigger

Comment: @OMGPonies Homework assignment

Comment: `:new.joined = extract(year from sysdate);` is the way to go.

Comment: @Bart My apologies I was unaware thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER foo2
BEFORE INSERT ON memberof
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    :new.joined := to_char(sysdate,'YYYY');
END;
```

For more information see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

and here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

BTW OMG Ponies is correct this normally should be done with default values which can take an expression like

```
to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')
```

as well.

Comment: joined is a number(4,0) data type, I'm getting PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error when I use this

Comment: That's a bad advice. You are relying on implicit data conversion by assigned a character value to a numeric column. Using `:new.joined = extract(year from sysdate)` is much cleaner.